# Аналог Android ViewPager для iOS заполняемый динамически

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Собственно интересует вопрос, как реализовать динамически заполняемый `ViewPager` в `iOS`.

На данный момент, я понимаю что для этого нужен `ScrollView` c включеной опцией "paging"

Есть ли возможность заполнять это все другими Вьюшками?

Например у меня есть вьюшка : `ImageView` на нем присутствуют несколько `TextLabel`.
я подгружаю данные из БД и поочереди вношу их в нужные элементы.

Под андройд, я создавал адаптер, заполнял массив объектов, и присваивал адаптер `ViewPager`.

Как подобное реализовать под iOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотри на [DVSlideViewController](https://github.com/dickverbunt/DVSlideViewController), может подойдет.

Comment: Спасибо) "Вкусный" Вариант) нужно рассмотреть его)